# ¿Cómo puedo mejorar el rendimiento y la indexación en una consulta donde se une una tabla consigo misma?

Tags: mysql

tengo la tabla principal "ventacompra" esta tabla se relaciona con otras tablas como factura o albarán, pero lo que estoy intentando hacer es una consulta que se relacione con la misma tabla, de tal manera que tabla a sea para el transación compra y la tabla b para la venta.

El resultado devuelto es correcto, pero el problema es a la hora de realizar la consulta que el tiempo es excesivo, como se puede apreciar más abajo en la explicación de la consulta está devolviendo todos los registros "17549"(pruebas en local en el servidor hay más de 100.000).

He creado dos indices, el primero ix1 que enlaza imei y transacion y el segundo indice ix2 con el estado con imei.

¿Como puedo crear un indice o mejorar la consulta para que sea más eficiente y no tenga que recorrer todos los registros?

Tabla ventacompra:

```
CREATE TABLE ventacompra (
`id_ventacompra` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`transacion` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`estado` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
`id_product` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`imei` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`modelo` VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
`precio_iva` DECIMAL(20,2) NOT NULL,
`precio_sin_iva` DECIMAL(20,2) NOT NULL,
`id_factura` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`id_albaran` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`fecha_registro` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`fecha_creacion` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`id_usuario` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`activo` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id_ventacompra`),
UNIQUE INDEX `id_nuevo` (`id_ventacompra`),
INDEX `ix1` (`imei`, `transacion`),
INDEX `ix2` (`estado`, `imei`)
);
```

La consulta:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT a.imei, a.id_product, a.modelo, a.precio_iva as precio_compra, b.precio_iva as precio_venta, a.id_factura AS id_factura_compra, a.id_albaran AS id_albaran_compra, 
b.id_factura AS id_factura_venta, b.id_albaran AS id_albaran_venta, a.estado,a.fecha_registro AS fecha_compra,b.fecha_creacion AS fecha_venta
FROM ventacompra a
LEFT JOIN ventacompra b on a.imei = b.imei AND a.transacion ='compra' AND b.transacion ='venta'   AND a.estado = 'nuevo' AND b.estado = 'nuevo' 
GROUP BY a.imei
```

Y este es el resultado de la "Explicación de la consulta":

[image: id select_type table partitions type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra "1" "SIMPLE" "a" (NULL) "ALL" "ix1,ix2" (NULL) (NULL) (NULL) "17549" "100,00" "Using temporary; Using filesort" "1" "SIMPLE" "b" (NULL) "ref" "ix1,ix2" "ix1" "124" "db_stack.a.imei,const" "1" "50,00" "Using where"]

Comment: El error es de diseño. Una venta es una venta y una compra es una compra. ¿Por qué las quieres expresar en una misma tabla? ¿Hay algo que justifique eso? Si lo piensas bien, lo mismo que tú expresas como tabla `a` y tabla `b` en tu consulta, deberían ser dos tablas distintas. Aquí, con los `AND` tú estás comparando cada fila consigo misma al tiempo que haces un JOIN de la tabla consigo misma. Eso no es viable, separa las compras y las ventas.

Comment: El diseño no está mal, ambas son transacciones que contienen los mismos atributos, cumple incluso con la 3era forma normal; en estos casos es mas cara una tabla que una columna. La consulta suplica por un índice exclusivamente sobre `imei`. También se puede intentar invertir `ix1`. Para que tome `ix2` hay que considerar el orden de las columnas.

Comment: @Sal, si he entendido bien, se está mezclando en una misma tabla `compras` y `ventas`, que son dos entidades totalmente distintas. ¿Dices que eso está bien?

Comment: @ A. Cedano : Si, de lo contrario sería común tener tablas `clientes` y `clientas` únicamente por el atributo `genero`.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, las tablas estaban ya creadas, de momento no tengo intención de modificarla ya que hay demasiadas consultas en la aplicación para hacer este cambio, sería buena opción pero de momento voy a empezar a solucionar este problema de la indexación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba seleccionando antes de combinar:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT a.imei, a.id_product, a.modelo, 
a.precio_iva as precio_compra,
b.precio_iva as precio_venta,
a.id_factura AS id_factura_compra,
a.id_albaran AS id_albaran_compra, 
b.id_factura AS id_factura_venta,
b.id_albaran AS id_albaran_venta,
a.estado,a.fecha_registro AS fecha_compra,
b.fecha_creacion AS fecha_venta
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM ventacompra
        WHERE transacion='compra'
        AND estado = 'nuevo'
) a LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM ventacompra
        WHERE transacion='venta'
        AND estado = 'nuevo'
) b ON a.imei = b.imei 
GROUP BY a.imei;
```

Al meter menos registros en la combinación, probablemente vaya más rápido.

Comment: Gracias amigo por la ayuda, pero me devuelve este error:
http://prntscr.com/11831v9

Comment: Perdona, fallo mío, ya está corregido: asignaba dos veces el alias. Por cierto, ¿para qué agrupas si no utilizas ninguna función de totales?

Comment: Gracias David, acabo de ejecutar la consulta y justo me devuelve la mitad de los registros, para mi es un avance, te lo agradezco, agrupo para que no se repitan los registros que contengan el mismo imei.

Comment: Entonces mejor usa `DISTINCT`, si no usas una función de totales te mostrará cualquiera de los registros, no un resumen de cada `imei`

Comment: Con la cláusula "DISTINCT" aparecen repetidos, la misma consulta agrupandolos por "GROUP BY" no aparecen repetidos y he comprobado que salen correctamente todos los registros que tienen que aparecer, gracias.